# disable NOTICES in psql output

Tags: database, postgresql, verbosity

How do I stop psql (PostgreSQL client) from outputting notices? e.g.

> psql:schema/auth.sql:20: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"

In my opinion a program should be silent unless it has an error, or some other reason to output stuff.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
SET client_min_messages TO WARNING;
```

[That](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) could be set only for the session or made persistent with [`ALTER ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html) or [`ALTER DATABASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html).

Or you could put that in your [".psqlrc"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN71686).

Comment: This can also be changed in postgresql.conf

Comment: ... Or just after `connect` by using some command like `do` or `execute` via any DBI interface.

Answer (score 71):

Probably the most comprehensive explanation is on Peter Eisentrauts [blog entry here](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2010/03/running-sql-scripts-with-psql.html) ([Archive](https://archive.li/Yi4KU))

I would strongly encourage that the original blog be studied and digested but the final recommendation is something like :

```
PGOPTIONS='--client-min-messages=warning' psql -X -q -a -1 -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --pset pager=off -d mydb -f script.sql
```

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to answer with just a link, but I agree that this was a very informative blog post. Please consider extracting some of the key points and summarizing them in your answer, along with the link.

Answer (score 25):

Use `--quiet` when you start psql.

A notice is not useless, but that's my point of view.

Comment: interesting... that shuts up all the stuff like `CREATE TABLE` but not the `NOTICE's` I'm not sure that I really think all of them are useless... but I do have a bit of a belief (and I think I read it in one of those must read C or Unix books) that programs should be quiet unless they have a problem or you tell them not to be. so --quiet should be the default and there should be a --verbose (perhaps with customizable levels)

Comment: NOTICE is still visible for me: SQL "alter table foo drop constraint if exists check_bar". Output: "NOTICE:  constraint "check_bar" of relation "foo" does not exist, skipping"

Comment: This removed the annoying "Pager usage is off." message for me so I adopted using `-q` in `psql` scripting from now on. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It can be set in the global `postgresql.conf` file as well with modifiying the `client_min_messages` parameter.

Example:

```
client_min_messages = warning
```

Comment: Actually this answer is the same as @Gavin posted with just the relevant part.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the various solutions suggested (and permutations thereof) suggested in this thread, but I was unable to completely suppress PSQL output / notifications.

I am executing a `claws2postgres.sh` BASH script that does some preliminary processing then calls/executes a PSQL .sql script, to insert 1000's of entries into PostgreSQL.

```
...
PGOPTIONS="-c client_min_messages=error"
psql -d claws_db -f claws2postgres.sql
```

**Output**

```
[victoria@victoria bash]$ ./claws2postgres.sh
 pg_terminate_backend 
----------------------

DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
You are now connected to database "claws_db" as user "victoria".
CREATE TABLE
SELECT 1
INSERT 0 1
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 1
Dropping tmp_table
DROP TABLE

You are now connected to database "claws_db" as user "victoria".
psql:/mnt/Vancouver/projects/ie/claws/src/sql/claws2postgres.sql:33: NOTICE:  42P07: relation "claws_table" already exists, skipping
LOCATION:  transformCreateStmt, parse_utilcmd.c:206
CREATE TABLE
SELECT 1
INSERT 0 1
UPDATE 2
UPDATE 2
UPDATE 2
Dropping tmp_table
DROP TABLE

[ ... snip ... ]
```

**SOLUTION**

Note this modified PSQL line, where I redirect the psql output:

```
psql -d claws_db -f $SRC_DIR/sql/claws2postgres.sql &>> /tmp/pg_output.txt
```

The `&>> /tmp/pg_output.txt` redirect appends all output to an output file, that can also serve as a log file.

**BASH terminal output**

```
[victoria@victoria bash]$ time ./claws2postgres.sh
 pg_terminate_backend 
----------------------

DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
2:40:54                       ## 2 h 41 min
[victoria@victoria bash]$
```

**Monitor progress:**

In another terminal, execute

```
PID=$(pgrep -l -f claws2postgres.sh | grep claws | awk '{ print $1 }'); while kill -0 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1; do NOW=$(date); progress=$(cat /tmp/pg_output.txt | wc -l);  printf "\t%s: %i lines\n" "$NOW" $progress; sleep 60; done; for i in seq{1..5}; do aplay 2>/dev/null /mnt/Vancouver/programming/scripts/phaser.wav && sleep 0.5; done
...
Sun 28 Apr 2019 08:18:43 PM PDT: 99263 lines
Sun 28 Apr 2019 08:19:43 PM PDT: 99391 lines
Sun 28 Apr 2019 08:20:43 PM PDT: 99537 lines
[victoria@victoria output]$
```

---

- `pgrep -l -f claws2postgres.sh | grep claws | awk '{ print $1 }'` gets the script PID, assigned to $PID
- `while kill -0 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1; do ...` : while that script is running, do ...
- `cat /tmp/pg_output.txt | wc -l` : use the output file line count as a progress indicator
- when done, notify by playing `phaser.wav` 5 times
- phaser.wav: https://persagen.com/files/misc/phaser.wav

---

**Output file:**

```
[victoria@victoria ~]$ head -n22 /tmp/pg_output.txt
You are now connected to database "claws_db" as user "victoria".
CREATE TABLE
SELECT 1
INSERT 0 1
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 1
Dropping tmp_table
DROP TABLE

You are now connected to database "claws_db" as user "victoria".
psql:/mnt/Vancouver/projects/ie/claws/src/sql/claws2postgres.sql:33: NOTICE:  42P07: relation "claws_table" already exists, skipping
LOCATION:  transformCreateStmt, parse_utilcmd.c:206
CREATE TABLE
SELECT 1
INSERT 0 1
UPDATE 2
UPDATE 2
UPDATE 2
Dropping tmp_table
DROP TABLE
```

---

**References**

- [re: solution, above] [PSQL: How can I prevent any output on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482382/psql-how-can-i-prevent-any-output-on-the-command-line)
- [re: this SO thread] [disable NOTICES in psql output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530767/disable-notices-in-psql-output?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [related SO thread] [Postgresql - is there a way to disable the display of INSERT statements when reading in from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777564/postgresql-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-display-of-insert-statements-when-rea)
- [relevant to solution] https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean

```
The > operator redirects the output usually to a file but it can be to a device. You can also use >> to append.
If you don't specify a number then the standard output stream is assumed but you can also redirect errors

  > file redirects stdout to file
  1> file redirects stdout to file
  2> file redirects stderr to file
  &> file redirects stdout and stderr to file

/dev/null is the null device it takes any input you want and throws it away. It can be used to suppress any output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Offering a suggestion that is useful for a specific scenario I had:

- Windows command shell calls psql.exe call to execute *one* essential SQL command
- Only want to see warnings or errors, and suppress NOTICES

Example:

```
psql.exe -c "SET client_min_messages TO WARNING; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytab CASCADE"
```

(I was unable to make things work with PGOPTIONS as a Windows environment variable--couldn't work out the right syntax. Tried multiple approaches from different posts.)