# Postgresql - is there a way to disable the display of INSERT statements when reading in from a file?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I populate a postgresql database from a file.

I get a lot of:

```
INSERT 0 1
```

statements.

Is there a way to not display these commands at all? They scroll away earlier output on my shell right now and do not yield a lot of useful information (what does INSERT 0 1 mean? is that like saying "yo dude the insert command was a success"?).

It seems I get one `INSERT 0 1` line for every `INSERT` statement in that `.sql` file I read from and this is a massive file.

Comment: A useful question, in my opinion. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907682/1904943

Answer (score 24):

[The `psql` manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) says:

> `-q`
>
> `--quiet`
>
> Specifies that psql should do its work quietly. By default, it prints welcome messages and various informational output. If this option is used, none of this happens. This is useful with the -c option. Within psql you can also set the `QUIET` variable to achieve the same effect.

Per @harmic's suggestion you may also want to set `client_min_messages`:

```
SET client_min_messages = 'ERROR';
```

Comment: In addition to that you may want to dial down the log level, which controls output of NOTICEs etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530767/disable-notices-in-psql-output

Comment: cool I think that answered my question, now I only have to find out how to mark this as checked ... hmmm

Comment: the client variable did the trick